# Disable UITableViewcontroller from rotating in Landscape (keep it Portrait)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios8.1

I'm trying to keep ***UITableViewcontroller*** in Portrait orientation. Hence, I don't want to rotate to Landscape mode. I added below method. But it didn't help, notice I'm using iOS 8:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
     if(interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        return YES;
    }else
    {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

Notice: I'm calling the UITableView through ***UINavigationController***

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                    initWithRootViewController:svc];
    // configure the new view controller explicitly here.




    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` has been deprecated since iOS 6.0. You should be using `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate`.

Here's how you do it:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

**EDIT** - for `UINavigationController`

This is one possible way to do it:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if ([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]])
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    else
        return [super preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]])
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    else
        return [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    if ([self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]])
        return NO;
    else
        return [super shouldAutorotate];
}
```

Note that you can't force the device orientation, so if the app is in landscape and you then push the table view controller, it will still be in landscape. There are a number of ways to handle this:

- Block the user from opening the table view controller by displaying an alert asking them to rotate the device first.
- Hide the table view and show a label with a message (or some other indicator) to tell the user to rotate their device.
- Handle both orientations.

Comment: ... thanks, but it still rotating ... notice i'm using storyboard, do this makes any difference.

Comment: Nope, shouldn't do. Add breakpoints in these methods to make sure that they're being called.

Comment: Oh, just noticed your update about the `UINavigationController`. You'll need to subclass *that* and override these methods to return `portrait` when the `visibleViewController` is your table view controller.

Comment: I appreciate if you could update your answer to explain how I do that. Because eI'm already subclassing UITableViewController ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: is depricated. Instead, use:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
     return NO;
 }
```